# PHP Magic methods not working

Tags: php

I am trying to create a registry class with magic `__set` and `__get` my class looks like

```
  class Registry {
      private $vars = array();

      public function __set($key, $value)
      {
          $this->vars[$key] = $value;
          dump($key, $value);
      }

      public function __get($index)
      {
          $this->vars[$index];
      }
  }
```

but if i try to save some variable in registry class in gets only the `$key` the `$value`
is alway NULL.

here is the sample code how I am try to call this class

```
$registry   = new registry; 
$registry->router = $router; 
$registry->title = "Welcome ";
```

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `dump()` and tell us what that displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You forgot to return value in the `__get` method
2. What does the `dump` function do?

Comment: But in __set the dump function displays a null value.

Comment: What does the `dump` function do? I didn't find it in the PHP manual. Did you mean `var_dump`, or it's your own function?

Comment: dump is a uder defined function. That displays a formates Dump with different coloring for arrays, objects, variables etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your __get function doesn't return a value, that's why it's always null. It should be:

`return $this->vars[$index];`